# ion-google-place not working with Android 6.0

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Does anyone know why ion-google-place doesn't work with Android 6.0? With Android 4 and 5 it reacts to typing in a place name by showing a list of options. With 6.0 nothing happens at all.

Is there a way to fix this?